# Отправка форм ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть код:

```
$('#pjaxcontainer form').live('submit',function(a){

 // display loading message
  $('#loading-shade').show();

  if( !$(a.target).attr('action'))
     a.target = $(a.target).closest('form');

  data = $(a.target).serialize();

  cont = $('#pjaxcontainer');

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: $(a.target).attr('action'),
     data: data,
     beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX','true'); // IMPORTANT
     },
     success: function(msg){
        cont.html(msg);
        $('#loading-shade').hide();
     },
     error: function(a,b,c) {
        $('#loading-shade').hide();
     }
  });

  a.preventDefault();
  return false;
```

});

Но он не отправляет данные кнопки, по которой происходит submit. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Какие-то странноватые у вас манипуляции. Плюс ко всему, вы не указали тип ожидаемых данных в ответе (**dataType**). [Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wrfE3/2/)

Comment: это часть плагина jquery-pjax, который загружает страницы через ajax (как ВК). Данный код должен сабмитить формы. Но почему-то он не отправляет данные <button> кнопок. А так работает.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что примерчик вы взяли из [статьи на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123972/). Просто передирать - это не есть гуд. Как создавать обработку форм, отправку через ajax - это должно остаться за вами и к pjax не имеет отношения, за исключением одного параметра, который вам отметили коментом **IMPORTANT**.

Comment: Да, из этой статьи. Обработчик форм есть и встроенный, как я заметил. Да и методы, устаревшие они или нет, работают. За исключением одного - не отправляют данные кнопки. С этим и прошу помочь.

Comment: По поводу того, что старые методы/функции работают, надо добавить: "**пока ещё работают**"! Вышла версия **jQuery 1.8** и в описании к ней сказано, что это переходная версия, подготовка к версии **1.9**, в которой будут удалены многие привычные нам функции. И версия **1.8**сделана, чтоб адаптировать народ к этому.

----------

Выкладывайте на jsFiddle ваш JS и HTML коды. Думаю, что это может помочь делу.